# Ruby on Rails multiple associations with the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a case where each user has many items and each item has many users.
However, I also want to assign a primary item to each user. I can't figure out what the best architectural decision is to achieve this. In the end I want to be able to call:

```
User.primary_item
```

Comment: I think your association before you edited could work. `:foreign_key` is supported on `has_one`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-one

That is, if an item can only have one owner. If several people can have the same item as their primary one, then maybe the association should go the other way.

Comment: With has_one though wouldn't it look for the foreign_key on the items table rather than the users table? Would belongs_to be better?

Comment: Yes, if the relation is that many users can have the same primary item, but one user can only have one such primary item, you can have a `primary_item_id` on users, and a `belongs_to` in User.

Comment: Of course, you'll need the join table for the many-to-many relation anyway, so why not go with a `has_many :through`, and set a property that it is the primary item in the join table.

`has_many :items, through: :item_users`
`has_one :primary_item, through: :item_users, -> { where primary: true }`

Comment: That's it. That join table already exists and designed that way (not as a HABTM) for this exact kind of possibility. Thanks!

Comment: I get the following with that code

`user.rb:62: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109238/discussion-between-rantingsonrails-and-martin-svalin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a has_many_through relationship.

```
class User
  has_many :owned_items
  has_many :items, through :owned_items
end

class Item
  has_many :owned_items
  has_many :users, through :owned_items
end

class OwnedItem
  belongs_to :items
  belongs_to :users
end
```

Rather than have a separate relationship for the primary_item, you could have a primary attribute on owned_item.

Comment: That would require a new table no? Would the following be simpler?
   
 belongs_to :primary_item, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => "primary_item_id"

Comment: @rantingsonrails, adding a `:foreign_key` goes against Rails conventions. I find adding a new table to be much easier than fighting Rails' conventions.

Comment: Your question states that "each user has many items and each item has many users". Its either a has_many_through or a has_many_and_belongs_to relationship. I think as you develop your app, you'll find that a has_many_through will provide you with many benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given, I'd say set up a [`has_many through:`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association on both models. On the `User` model, add a column for `primary_item_id` then add a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) to the `User` model called `primary_item` that fetches that user's primary item. Note, a `has_many through:` association will require you to also create an associated join table, `UserItems`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_items
  has_many :items, through: :user_items
  scope :primary_item, -> { Item.find(self.primary_item_id) }
end

class UserItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_items
  has_many :users, through: :user_items
end
```

That's the relevant information for the `ActiveRecord` models. You'll also need to run migrations to create the `UserItems` table and add the `primary_item_id` column to the `Users` table. Note that you aren't using `:foreign_key` anywhere here.

Comment: He wants MANY items and ONE user item. I think all you need is a field in Users table to point to record in Items table. No need for another table.

Comment: @Kalman, you are wrong. As quoted from his question *"I have a case where each user has many items and each item has many users."* It is a many to many relationship. He **also wants to assign a primary item to each user.*

Comment: That's correct. User and Item are a many-to-many between each other. User ALSO has a has-one to his primary item.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you'll want a join table for that many-to-many association. The has_one association is modeled separately with the addition of a column on the `User` model (or, as @rantingonrails seems to have chosen, as a column on the join table).

Comment: Oh I think I see the miscommunication. In my example code, `user_items` is the name of the join table. Perhaps you mistook that for the primary_item.